# Spark: Create Single Column Complex Type Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

Suppose I have a case class as follows:

`final case class Person(name: String, age: Int)`

I'd like to create a single column dataframe that has a complex StructType of `Person`. I want spark to infer the schema.

```
val data = Seq(Person("Tom", 30), Person("Anna", 35))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
```

I want spark to infer that the dataframe is a single column with complex type of `Person`. Currently, it splits `Person` up into multiple columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the data to the desired structure.

A helper class:

```scala
case class PersonWrapper(person: Person)
```

Now there are two options:

1. [Mapping](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/Seq.html#map%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EB):CC%5BB%5D) the scala sequence before creating the Spark dataframe:

```scala
val df = spark.createDataFrame(data.map( PersonWrapper(_)))
```

or

2. [mapping](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#map%5BU%5D(func:T=%3EU)(implicitevidence$6:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder%5BU%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BU%5D) the Spark dataframe/dataset:

```scala
val df = spark.createDataset(data).map(PersonWrapper(_))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use:

```
final case class PersonAttributes(name: String, age: Int)
final case class Person(attributes: PersonAttributes)
```

then:

```
val data = Seq(
  Person(PersonAttributes("Tom", 30)),
  Person(PersonAttributes("Anna", 35))
)
```

Or you can create the dataset as you are, then using `withColumn` with `struct` to create the complex structure you want:

```
.withColumn("data", struct(col("name"), col("age")))
```

Good luck!